# Generating random geolocations within specific radius from given point using Golang

Tags: random, go-golang

I am having trouble generating random geo locations from a given locations at a certain radius. I am getting an incorrect coordinate with the implementation I have done.

How could I achieve the needed functionality?

```
type Location struct{
   Latitude     float64
   Longitude    float64
}

const EarthRadius = 6371000 /* meters  */
const DegToRad =  math.Pi / 180.0
const ThreePi = math.Pi*3
const TwoPi float64 = math.Pi*2


func pointAtDistance(location Location, radius float64) Location{
// Convert Degrees to radians
    loc := toRadians(location)

    sinLat := math.Sin(loc.Latitude)
    cosLat := math.Cos(loc.Latitude)

    bearing := rand.Float64() * TwoPi
    theta := radius / EarthRadius
    sinBearing := math.Sin(bearing)
    cosBearing := math.Cos(bearing)
    sinTheta   := math.Sin(theta)
    cosTheta   := math.Cos(theta)

   latitude := math.Asin(sinLat * cosTheta + cosLat*sinTheta*cosBearing)
    longitude := location.Longitude +
    math.Atan2(sinBearing * sinTheta*cosLat, (cosTheta-sinLat) * math.Sin(latitude))


    /* normalize -PI -> +PI radians */
    longitude = math.Mod(longitude+ThreePi, TwoPi) - math.Pi

     locs := toDegrees(Location{
        Latitude: latitude,
        Longitude: longitude,
    })

    return Location{
         Latitude: locs.Latitude,
         Longitude: locs.Longitude,
   }
}

 func GenerateLocations(location Location, radius float64) Location{
    rnd := rand.Float64()
    ranDist := math.Sqrt(rnd) * radius
     return pointAtDistance(location, ranDist)
}

 func toRadians(location Location) Location{
     lat := location.Latitude * DegToRad
     lon := location.Longitude * DegToRad

    return Location{
        Latitude: lat,
        Longitude: lon,
   }
}

func toDegrees(location Location) Location{
    lat := location.Latitude / DegToRad
    lon := location.Longitude / DegToRad

    return Location{
       Latitude: lat,
       Longitude: lon,
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

**Input**

```
func main(){
    location:= GenerateLocations(Location{
        Latitude: 6.981106276681917,
        Longitude: 79.87749937315392,
     }, 100)
    fmt.Println(location)
  }
```

**Output**

{6.981757300245991 -103.35666511967649}

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide sample input and output.

Comment: @Vince I have done the needed edit you have suggested. Thank you.